# What is the difference between ".scan" and ".split" in Ruby language?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between ".scan" and ".split" in Ruby language?

Can someone give me an example?

i am really got confused about it!

Answer (score 1):

- `scan` extracts substrings that match the given regex.
- `split` extracts substrings that do not match the given regex (and optionally, substrings that match as well).